# Timeline.js как сделать даты в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, php

Сейчас порядок временной шкалы - 2020->2021->2022, но нам нужно сделать наоборот, 2022->2021->2020. Я не нашел никаких настроек в самой библиотеке. Как это можно сделать?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/works/jquery.timeline.min.js"></script>

$('.timelineLight').timeline({
            openTriggerClass: '.trigger_open',
            itemMargin: 44,
            startItem: 'first',
});

код который устанавливает порядок дат по возрастанию 
надо сделать по убыванию
                    var currYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
                    if(maxY>currYear) maxY = currYear;



                    while (minY <= maxY || minM != maxM) {
                        if(minY>currYear) break;
                        html.push ('<div class="t_line_view" data-id="' + cnt + '" style="position:relative; display:inline-block;">\n' + (data.options.yearsOn ? '<h3 class="t_line_year" style="text-align:center; width:100%">' + minY + '</h3>\n' : '') + '<div class="t_line_m" style="position:absolute; top:0;">\n' + '<h4 class="t_line_month" style="position:abolute; width:100% top:0; text-align:center;">' + months[minM] + (data.options.yearsOn ? '<span class="t_line_month_year"> ' + minY + '</span>' : '') + '</h4>\n');

                        for (var x in nodes) {

                            var dataArray = x.split('/');
                            m = (months.indexOf(dataArray[1]) != -1) ? months.indexOf(dataArray[1]) : parseInt(dataArray[1], 10);
                            if (!data.options.yearsOn)y = minY; else y = parseInt(dataArray[2], 10);
                            if (m == minM && y == minY) {
                                html.push (nodes[x]);
                                nodes.splice(x, 1)
                            }
                        }
                        minM++;
                        html.push ('</div>\n' + '<div class="t_line_m right" style="position:absolute; top:0;">\n' + '<h4 class="t_line_month" style="position:abolute; width:100% top:0; text-align:center;">' + months[minM] + (data.options.yearsOn ? '<span class="t_line_month_year"> ' + minY + '</span>' : '') + '</h4>\n');

                        for (var x in nodes) {
                            dataArray = x.split('/');

                            m = (months.indexOf(dataArray[1]) != -1) ? months.indexOf(dataArray[1]) : parseInt(dataArray[1], 10);
                            if (!data.options.yearsOn)y = minY; else y = parseInt(dataArray[2], 10);
                            if (m == minM && y == minY) {
                                html.push(nodes[x]);
                                nodes.splice(x, 1)
                            }
                        }
                        html.push ('</div>\n' + '<div style="clear:both"></div>\n' + '</div>');
                        if (minM == months.length - 1) {
                            minM = 1;
                            minY++
                        } else {
                            minM++
                        }
                        cnt++
                    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]